# Solving the Sine Gordon PDE in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

how can i solve this equation in mathematica?
this is sine-gordon eq.
but the boundary condition can not recognized by mathematica .
thank you for you attention.

```
NDSolve[{∂_(x,x) F[t,x]==(1-ζ)(Sin[F[t,x]]+β∂_t F[t,x]+∂_(t,t) F[t,x]),...
(∂_x F[t,x]==∂_t  F[t,x]/.x→0),(∂_x F[t,x]==∂_t F[t,x]/.x→1)},F,{t,0,10},{x,0,1}]
```

### Edit:

```
\[Beta] = 1;
\[Zeta] = 1;
NDSolve[
 {
  D[f[t, x], x, 
    x] == (1 - \[Zeta]) Sin[[t, x]] + \[Beta] D[f[t, x], t] + 
    D[f[t, x], t, t],
  D[f[t, 0], x] == D[f[t, 0], t],
  D[f[t, 1], x] == D[f[t, 1], t]

  },
 f,
 {t, 0, 10},
 {x, 0, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Try to solve an easier PDE first to get a grip on the syntax.

Comment: your syntax is incorrect; try looking in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html) where they have [examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html#197355455) of solving PDEs.

Comment: This is the Sine Gordon wave equation like you say. Check [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine-GordonEquation.html) out. Also, if you could correct your syntax you might have better luck...

Comment: I tried editting the equation. However, theres probably insufficient boundary condition and initial condition information to solve this.

Answer (score 9):

As the comments say, you really have to learn correct syntax.

Set up Sine-Gordon equation with initial and boundary conditions:

```
eq = {D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] == Sin[u[t, x]] + D[u[t, x], {x, 2}], 
  u[0, x] == E^(-x^2), Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, 
  u[t, -10] == u[t, 10]};
```

Solve it:

```
sol = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, -10, 10}];
```

Plot it:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]], 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotPoints -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I love this equation!

Comment: Vitaliy: Your plot is (as usually) a piece of artwork. Have you written something about creating aesthetically pleasant graphs with Mma? (And if you haven't, could  you?)

Comment: that's a great colour scheme

Comment: @belisarius thanks, i'm glad you guys like it. i have to find some time - but i'd really love to ;)